# Symbolizing tippecanoe tiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, qgis-expression

I have tiled point data using tippecanoe. When I load mbtiles into QGIS, it loads and works ok.

When I click on points I get feature values and all the attributes. Im looking to symbolise the points from feature values using expressions. The only two options I get is vector_tile_zoom and zoom_level to be included into expression.

[image]

How can I access the  fields and attributes using expressions? When I look into the expression builder in 'Fields and Values' I see only NULL.

[image]

Specifically for instance I would want  values between 1 and 20 from field 'CODE' to be red, values from 21 to 50 to be blue, and so on.